# How to show the hidden .svn folder on MAC OSX Finder

Tags: macos, svn

I have checked out a subversion repository on my MAC. But I cannot see the .svn folder that I can see on my Windows (with show hidden files/folder option checked). How do I do that in Finder? I am using the latest Versions app for subversion

Comment: Why do you want to find it? Unless you understand Subversion internals, you shouldn't be poking around in there anyway.

Comment: You are right. But I sometimes need to delete the .svn folder to remove source control from a folder. But anyway, I think your suggestion makes sense.

Comment: In  your original post, you should explain what your end goal is so that you get the best possible answer (instead of what you think the solution is and only getting answers that are tangentially related to what you're trying to achieve). In this case, should be able to use [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) to "export" a working copy over itself to remove the directory. Or in Terminal, just `rm -rf .svn` from the root of the working copy.

Comment: @alroc thanks for your comment and tips. It seems that there is no way for Finder to show hidden .svn folder/or any other hidden folder I guess. But Terminal can see and delete the .svn folder, so there is that.

Comment: If you can't see hidden files in MAC's Finder, simply press SHIFT + CMD + . (dot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, this folder appears as a directory named .subversion in the user's home directory. MacOS is UNIX. Hidden files/directories are not shown in Finder by default.

You can either:

Open up Terminal and cd .subversion - you'll be into the directory.

or

Use Mac Terminal to show hidden files ([from this link](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/)):

Open Terminal (click Go > Utilities and double-click the Terminal
app)

Now copy and paste both lines listed below into Terminal one at a
time, and press Return after each line:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

killall Finder
```

Finder should reset and then start showing hidden files/folders.

Comment: I tried the later approach to make Finder show the .svn folder but to no avail. But I can see .svn in terminal. Thanks.

Comment: In my case SHIFT + CMD + . (dot) helped to see hidden folders in Finder

Answer (score 6):

**Toggle Hidden Files / Folders**

Make sure you are in Finder, and use the keyboard shortcut -

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (this will display / hide the hidden files & folders)

**Navigate to Hidden Folder**

Again, make sure you are in Finder, and use the keyboard shortcut
 -

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
(this will display a search box where you then type in the path to the file. *note: You can use tab completion the same as you would in terminal.app)